# Makefile: how to avoid specifying all targets manually

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I wrote this Makefile:

```
all: clean basedemo.exe

clean:
  rm -f *.exe

%.exe: %.s
  vasmm68k_mot -kick1hunks -Fhunkexe -o $@ -nosym $<
```

My goal would be to compile every `.s` file in the current folder to a separate `.exe`.

Right now, I have to append the new `.exe` file name to the line: `all: clean basedemo.exe new_file.exe`

Is there a way to avoid having to do that?

Thank you

I tried using a wildcard:

`all: clean $(wildcard *.exe)`

But when I run `make all` only the clean recipe runs.

Comment: Just to note, it's bizarre to have `all` depend on `clean`.  The entire point of make is to rebuild things that are out of date and not rebuild things that are not out of date.  If you want to rebuild everything every single time you don't need a makefile: a simple shell script will do fine.  Also, if you ever want to use parallel builds (`make -j`) then this will fail badly because the `clean` recipe will run concurrently with the build recipes.

Comment: Understood, that is true. Will correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(wildcard *.exe)` searchs for existing `.exe` files, but they do not exist yet when you run `make`.

What you can do is to find all `.s` files and substitute their extension to `.exe`:

```
FILES_S:=$(wildcard *.s)
FILES_EXE:=$(FILES_S:%.s=%.exe)

all : clean $(FILES_EXE);
```